# SAPUI5: Binding controller properties to the view

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to bind properties from my controller to the view.

in angularjs it's as simple as manipulating the $scope:

```
$scope.buttonProps = {
    value: 'cheese',
    disabled: 'disabled',
    onClick: function() {}
};

<custom-button disabled="buttonProps.disabled" onclick="buttonProps.onClick" value="{{buttonProps.value}}" />
```

however when I try to do the same in SAPUI5

```
sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend('...', {
    buttonProps: {
        value: 'cheese',
        disabled: 'disabled',
        onClick: function() {}
    }
});

<custom-button value="{buttonProps.value}" disabled="{buttonProps.disabled}" click="buttonProps.onClick" />
```

it does not work - the framework doesn't seem to be able to access the properties of the "buttonProps" object.

if I, however, move the properties directly onto the controller, it works

```
sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend('...', {
    value: 'cheese',
    disabled: 'disabled',
    onClick: function() {}
});

<custom-button value="{value}" disabled="{disabled}" click="onClick" />
```

but of course, this is a very disorganised way of working when you get more complex views.

I tried creating a JSONModel and binding the values via the model:

```
sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend('...', {
    buttonProps: new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        value: 'cheese',
        disabled: 'disabled',
        onClick: function() {}
    })

    onAfterRendering: function() {
        this.byId('btn').setModel(this.buttonProps);
    }
});

<custom-button id="btn" value="{/value}" disabled="{/disabled}" click="/onClick" />
```

and it works for everything... except for functions.

is there a way for me to bind properties from my controller to the view?

Answer (score 1):

UI5 follows the [M-V-C](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) paradigm and event handler is not part of data model.

The correct way to do data binding is as following:

**View:**

The `onClick` is defined as a function in the controller not in the data model.

```
<custom-button id="btn" value="{/value}" disabled="{/disabled}" click="onClick" />
```

**Controller:**

```
sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend('...', {

    buttonProps: new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        value: 'cheese',
        disabled: 'disabled'
    }),

    onInit: function() {
        this.byId('btn').setModel(this.buttonProps);
    },

    onClick:function(oEvent) {

    }    

});
```

Comment: Yeah that's all cool, exactly as I thought - thanks for correcting my syntax. But why did they design the framework so that I can't organise my methods within sub-objects? Like why can't I define ``buttonMethods: {onClick:...}`` on my controller and then attach the function to the button: ``... click="buttonMethods.onClick" ...``

Comment: why you need to sub-objects? View usually has one controller with controllerName attribute defined in XML view.

Comment: I would like to have sub-objects to organise my methods to make the code more maintainable. Rather than having 5 different onClick methods with a weird naming convention like nameButtonOnClick, streetButtonOnClick, etc, I'd like to organise each button's function handlers into a sub-object, so that they are grouped together. I.e. nameButton: {onClick:..., onHover:...}, streetButton: {onClick:...,onHover...}. That way the code is easier to manage and it is ultimately easy to maintain.

Comment: You can have named models - for example, if you had a model called *buttonProps*, you could then refer to your properties as `disabled="{buttonProps>/disabled}"` etc. - just be sure to name your model when you create it.